# How to do in pandas dataframe to conditional change values

Tags: python, pandas

Put  dataframe like:

```
DT  s1  f1  s2  f2  s3  f3  s4  f4  s5  f5  s6  f6  s7  f7  s8  f8  s9  f9
200520160941    35  200408100500.0  12  200408100400    16  200408100300    11  200408100200    19  200408100100    35  200408100000    43  200408095500    00      00  
200507173541    00  190904192701.0  00      00      00      00      00      00      00      00  
200507173547    00  190908185501.0  08  190908185501    00      00      00      00      00      00      00  
200507173547    00  190908205601.0  08  190908205601    00      00      00      00      00      00      00  
200507173547    00  190909005800.0  08  190909005800    00      00      00      00      00      00      00  
200507173547    00  190908225701.0  08  190908225701    00      00      00      00      00      00      00  
200507173547    00  190909025901.0  08  190909025901    00      00      00      00      00      00      00  
200507173547    00  190909070101.0  08  190909070101    00      00      00      00      00      00      00
```

How to do in pandas dataframe to obtain as result a DataFrame where:

```
 s1 = np.NaN   if  f1 = np.NaN 
 s2 = np.NaN   if  f2 = np.NaN 
 …
 s9 = np.NaN   if  f9 = np.NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do:

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    df[f's{i}'] = df[f's{i}'].where(df[f'f{i}'].notna(), np.nan)
```

you could do (too):

```
isna = df[[f'f{i}' for i in range(1, 10)]].isna()
df[[f's{i}' for i in range(1, 10)]] += (isna[~isna] + 0).values
```